# Lucene fulltext query spellchecking

Tags: java, lucene, spell-checking

We have homegrown search engine based on Lucene and I'm intrested in the algorithms and tools for spellchecking ("Did you mean" feature).

Does Lucene contains some examples of such a functionality or maybe other open source community does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is  SpellChecker that you can use. It requires building a dictionary of your words based on which suggestions are matched. Here is a related post

["Did you mean?" feature in Lucene.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348093/did-you-mean-feature-in-lucene-net)