# find common misspelled searches in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

IS there a way to find common misspellings in sql server?For example, if I had a legitimate search… like “Forclosure” instead of “Foreclosure”, is there a way to find the connection within a table without doing LIKE or CASE WHEN?

Comment: You might be able to use some [fuzzy matching techniques](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921978/fuzzy-matching-using-t-sql) to find something similar to the search string. But this question has more to do with text searching than with SQL, so you might want to look at something like Lucene, which supports this [feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348093/did-you-mean-feature-in-lucene-net).

Answer (score 1):

I’m not 100% sure it will work but you can try experimenting with [SOUNDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx) function and see if it can give you any results.

SOUNDEX converts an alphanumeric string to a four-character code that is based on how the string sounds when spoken.

For example:

`SELECT SOUNDEX ('Smith'), SOUNDEX ('Smythe');`

Gives same results for both